# Bounty Expired on a Question Without Answer and Points were not Reclaimed

Tags: support, bounty

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happens if my bounty time expires?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3144/what-happens-if-my-bounty-time-expires)

I posted a 100 point bounty for [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128492/understanding-proof-about-an-immersion) but the bounty expired while the question remained unanswered. The 100 points however were never returned to my account. How to fix this?

Comment: This came up many times already, e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3144/5363) and [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/2321/5363) and [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3356/5363).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [FAQ section on bounties](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty) states,

> In any case, you will always give up the amount of reputation specified in the bounty

Alternately, see the [info section](https://math.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties) about the privilege level that grants one the ability to give bounties:

> Please note that once a bounty is started, the reputation is non-refundable under any circumstances.

So, I'm afraid your 100 points are lost.

Comment: Well, that sux.