# Issue with bounty

Tags: discussion, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happens if my bounty time expires?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3144/what-happens-if-my-bounty-time-expires)

I have kept a bounty of 50 to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131627/geometric-explanation-of-tamagawa-numbers) question, and it has gone unanswered, but the web-site is asking me to offer the bounty as soon as possible.

So is there anyway I could get back my points, and is there any way that I could re-open the bounty with 500 this time to receive special attention.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can't get back your points from a bounty you've already placed - see [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3144/what-happens-if-my-bounty-time-expires).

However, after your 50-point bounty expires you are welcome to place a new, 500-point bounty.

Comment: It has expired but I am unable to do it, could you help me settling that issue ? @Zev Chonoles.