# Expired bounty without a good answer?

Tags: support, bounty

My bounty is expired on my question: [Name of the class of graphs obtained by deleting $\mathcal{Q}_d$ from $\mathcal{Q}_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1745693/name-of-the-class-of-graphs-obtained-by-deleting-mathcalq-d-from-mathcal) - and I must award it within 24 hours. The only answer was down-voted (not by me), and does not answer the question whatsoever. What should I do in this case? Is there anything I can do besides awarding the bounty anyhow?

Comment: Related: [What happens if my bounty time expires?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3144)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not manually award the bounty it will go the earliest answer which satisfies **all** the following conditions:

1. It was posted after the bounty was set.
2. Has score $2$ or higher.

If there is only one answer, and its score is negative, you can just do nothing.

(See also [the Help Center on the bounty privilege](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties).)