# What do you do with a bounty if answers are not good enough?

Tags: discussion, bounty, best-practices

I've offered four bounties before, and two of those times I didn't find any answer good enough. Last time that happened, I just awarded it to the only answer but I'm wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: If the answers don't satisfy you, let the bounty fizzle (although, if an answer posted during the bounty period gets a score of at least 2, the system awards half the bounty to the highest-scoring answer posted during the bounty period, if you don't award the bounty yourself, so to let it truly fizzle, you need the voters to play along). But commenting on the answer(s) explaining why you don't find them satisfactory, giving the authors the chance to address those issues would be a good idea. Then you may get an answer you're happy to award the bounty to.

Comment: @DanielFischer I have commented, and received no answer although the user who posted the answer was online after I posted the comment.

Comment: Sometimes I come to the realization: when I put up a bounty, I am paying for the extra exposure, not for any prospective answer.

Comment: Sometimes I come to the realization: when I put up a bounty, sometimes I don't get any good answers. I'm asking what to do when no answer satisfies what I want, not saying that a bounty means that I will necessarily receive answers.

Comment: A somewhat similar question: [Expired bounty without a good answer?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23094)