# An answer that did not answer my question might get some reputation points from the bounty

Tags: support, bounty

A few days ago I asked this question: [My question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3722435/solving-textbfrt-fracgmrt3-textbfrt)

That question was on an exam my teacher gave us to help us prepare to the final exam. I only got one answer but the answer claimed that I made a mistake writing the equation (which I did not) and then solved the modified version of that equation. Although the solution for the modified equation is right, he basically modified the equation that I was trying to solve and that I wanted help to solve.

Yesterday I started a bounty and now the reputation might go to that answer. How should I proceed?

Comment: Once you agree to have points deducted to offer a bounty, you lose those points.  If no other answer is posted, you can choose not to award the bounty, but if you do so, 1/2 of the bounty will be awarded.to the upvoted answer.  You will not regain any of the 50 rep you offered for the bounty.

Comment: But note that you have six days left on the bounty, and others may likely yet answer.  So don't worry too much upon this.

Comment: your question may have no minus sign, but the use of gravitational constant $G$ says it was meant to have a minus sign.

Comment: @MattSamuel Actually, half of the bounty might still be awarded by the system under certain conditions. See the section "What happens if I feel my question is still unanswered? / What is automatic awarding?" in the FAQ post: [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065#16067) ([current revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/16067/89)).

Comment: The answer, as answered is correct.  You failed to note that the gravitational constant G is meant to have a minus sign, as @WillJagy notes.  That's your error, not the answerer's.

Comment: Similar question: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28210/what-happens-if-the-answer-which-had-appeared-after-starting-a-bounty-is-not-wor

Comment: @GerryMyerson IMO the fact that the answer to the question mentioned here is posted before the bounty started makes your linked post not so similar. In this case the bounty will not be awarded no matter how much reputation that answer receives unless OP wants to award the bounty there (since the answer it's posted before the bounty).

Comment: Ignoring the context of the question, you can flag the answer as "not an answer" if it answered a different question than yours, but what I'd suggest is to include the full context in the question body (you only mentioned here that's from a past exam).// In any case there's no way it's your error, but perhaps it's your teacher making a typo with a minus sign. Have you tried to ask your teacher about that?

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this as the answer from the duplicated question is not relevant at all here. As I mentioned before, in this case the answer was posted before the bounty.

Comment: I'm sorry if my comment led to the (temporary) closure of the question. I did say the other question was similar; I didn't say it was a duplicate; I hoped users would inspect both questions carefully before making any decision on voting to close.